# Употребление таких слов, как "грамотность", во множественном числе

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, множественное-число

Есть в русском языке слова, обозначающие явления или свойства. Например (примеры намеренно взяты из разных областей): грамотность (хорошее владение языком), любовь (чувство), тавтология (смысловая избыточность), ударение (выделение силой голоса), нежность (проявление нежных чувств), геометрия (наука). Казалось бы, откуда тут взяться множественному числу, а на практике все эти слова употребляется во мн. ч. Как знать, корректно ли употреблено мн. ч. в каждом конкетном случае?

Вот несколько спорных примеров:

- Была ли взаимность во всех моих **любовях**? (Циолковский)
- Постановка **ударений**
- **Нежности** для любимого
- Текст содержит множество **тавтологий**
- Учебные задания, направленные на формирование предметных **грамотностей** (Педагогика и психология высшей школы. В данном сборнике представлены материалы Международной научной конференции, посвященной 10-летию создания кафедры педагогики и психологии высшей школы в Московском гуманитарном университете)

Есть ли какие-то общие правила, критерии на этот счет или каждый случай нужно рассматривать отдельно?

Comment: Слово *ударение* имеет формы мн. ч.; почему вы включили его в свой список?

Comment: @Aer Формально все эти слова имеют форму мн. ч. Вопрос, когда ее можно употреблять.

Comment: Нет, не все. *Любовь*, *тавтология*, *грамотность*, *нежность* «формально» вообще не имеют форм мн. ч. (см. словари)... Окказионализмы не в счет, они не формальные.

Comment: @Aer В Викисловаре есть мн. ч. у всех этих слов. А в каком словаре нет?

Comment: в любом бумажном :) Дело в том, что наличие форм слова в Викисловаре не говорит о том, что эти самые формы общеупотребительны. Викисловарь устроен довольно-таки сложно и, к сожалению, слишком ненадежен.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно общим языковым нормам,  отвлеченные существительные "ударение", "тавтология", "грамотность" не имеют множественного числа.
Однако частные стилистические нормы научного функционального стиля допускают употребление отвлеченных существительных во множественном числе, которые при этом приобретают конкретное терминологическое значение.
Формы "ударений", "тавтологий", "грамотностей" употреблены  в научном контексте, и их следует рассматривать как функционально прикрепленные.
Формы же "любовей", "нежностей" носят экспрессивный, фигуральный характер. Здесь имеет место быть сознательное нарушение нормы, выразительный прием, который в традиционной риторике квалифицировался как ***эналлага*** или "коммутация" (лат. *commutatio* — «изменение»).Согласно подходу Е.И.Шендельс, в свою очередь развивавшей идеи Р.Якобсона  и Э. Оскар, последние случаи можно также рассматривать как "грамматические метафоры" (Шендельс Е.И. Грамматическая метафора //Филологические науки, 1972, № 3).